# Under what conditions does a Rails after_filter run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Under what conditions does a Rails `after_filter` run in Rails 3.1? Is it based on the method's return value?

I have tried to find documentation on this, but have not succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the return value has an effect on an after_filter.

From the RoR Guides:

> After filters are similar to before filters, but because the action has already been run they have access to the response data that’s about to be sent to the client. Obviously, after filters cannot stop the action from running.

[source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#after-filters-and-around-filters)